# android studio switch how to pro-grammatically set the state of the switch

Tags: java, android-studio, uiswitch

I have a switch which I check the state of and then update a global settings class from.

However, when I reopen the activity the switch defaults back to its off state.
How do I set it in the oncreate to pull from my settings.

To pull the boolean state of my switch I do:

```
Boolean setting_variable = global_settings.Get_Advanced_settings();
```

Then I want something like:

```
my_switch.state(setting_variable);//Set the switch state
```

Comment: Use Preferences to save the state of the switch. Check it in oncreate and then use
my_switch.setChecked(boolean)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Do you need the code for it?

Comment: Its ok I just needed the API call. ```switch_advanced_mode.setChecked(global_settings.Get_Advanced_settings());```

Comment: Ok, moved my comment to answers, please mark as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Preferences to save the state of the switch. Check it in oncreate and then use my_switch.setChecked(boolean)